# A script to create a SVG path between different DIVs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I want to create a dynamic SVG path between my words DIVs.
[This is what I have for now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPoux.png) and [this is what I excepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmhR3.png).

Can you explain me why my code didn't work ?
I've tryed to determinate XY position of points of my SVG path depending by the start or the end of my words, and create the path with these coordinates

```
HTML :

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <title>SVG Path Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="word" id="w1" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 1%;">Premier</div>
    <div class="word" id="w2" style="margin-left: 60%; margin-top: 2%;">Deuxième</div>
    <div class="word" id="w3" style="margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 3%;">Troisième</div>
    <div class="word" id="w4" style="margin-left: 70%; margin-top: 4%;">Quatrième</div>
    <div class="word" id="w5" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-top: 5%;">Cinquième</div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


JavaScript :

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const wa = document.getElementById("w1");
    const wb = document.getElementById("w2");
    const wc = document.getElementById("w3");
    const wd = document.getElementById("w4");
    const we = document.getElementById("w5");
    const svgPath = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");

    const x1 = wa.offsetLeft + wa.offsetWidth;
    const y1 = wa.offsetTop + wa.offsetHeight / 2;

    const x2 = wb.offsetLeft;
    const y2 = wb.offsetTop + wb.offsetHeight / 2;

    const x3 = wc.offsetLeft + wc.offsetWidth;
    const y3 = wc.offsetTop + wc.offsetHeight / 2;

    const x4 = wd.offsetLeft;
    const y4 = wd.offsetTop + wd.offsetHeight / 2;

    const x5 = we.offsetLeft + we.offsetWidth;
    const y5 = we.offsetTop + we.offsetHeight / 2;

    // svgPath.setAttribute("d", M${x1},${y1} L${x2},${y2});
    svgPath.setAttribute("d", `M ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2} ${x3},${y3} ${x4},${y4} ${x5},${y5}`);
    svgPath.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
    svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
    svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "none");

    document.body.appendChild(svgPath);

});


CSS :

.word {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
  }

  #container {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: an SVG path element must have an SVG element as its parent e.g. <svg>

Comment: Can you show me how can I add it to correct my code please ? I'm begginer with SVG path

Comment: I guess [you need to read this](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/IG/resources/svgprimer.html) then.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Robert Longson:
you need a parent svg element to render the connecting line paths.

You can prepend an absolutely positioned `<svg>` to your container div like so:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  const container = document.getElementById("container");
  const wa = document.getElementById("w1");
  const wb = document.getElementById("w2");
  const wc = document.getElementById("w3");
  const wd = document.getElementById("w4");
  const we = document.getElementById("w5");


  const x1 = wa.offsetLeft + wa.offsetWidth;
  const y1 = wa.offsetTop + wa.offsetHeight / 2;

  const x2 = wb.offsetLeft;
  const y2 = wb.offsetTop + wb.offsetHeight / 2;

  const x3 = wc.offsetLeft + wc.offsetWidth;
  const y3 = wc.offsetTop + wc.offsetHeight / 2;

  const x4 = wd.offsetLeft;
  const y4 = wd.offsetTop + wd.offsetHeight / 2;

  const x5 = we.offsetLeft + we.offsetWidth;
  const y5 = we.offsetTop + we.offsetHeight / 2;

  // create parent svg
  const svg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
  // apply same dimensions as container element to svg 
  svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 1500 900");
  svg.setAttribute(
    "style",
    "position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; left:0; top:0;"
  );
  const svgPath = document.createElementNS(ns, "path");
  // svgPath.setAttribute("d", M${x1},${y1} L${x2},${y2});
  svgPath.setAttribute(
    "d",
    `M ${x1},${y1} L ${x2},${y2} ${x3},${y3} ${x4},${y4} ${x5},${y5}`
  );
  svgPath.setAttribute("stroke", "black");
  svgPath.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
  svgPath.setAttribute("fill", "none");


  // append to container div
  svg.append(svgPath);
  container.insertBefore(svg, container.children[0]);

});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#container {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 900px;
  //max-width:100%;
  aspect-ratio: 15/9;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="word" id="w1" style="margin-left: 10%; margin-top: 1%;">Premier</div>
  <div class="word" id="w2" style="margin-left: 60%; margin-top: 2%;">Deuxième</div>
  <div class="word" id="w3" style="margin-left: 20%; margin-top: 3%;">Troisième</div>
  <div class="word" id="w4" style="margin-left: 70%; margin-top: 4%;">Quatrième</div>
  <div class="word" id="w5" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-top: 5%;">Cinquième</div>
</div>
```

### Alternative: render everything to svg

Provided you only need to draw rather simple text elements, you might use svg `<text>`.

```js
let words = [
  { text: "Premier", x: "10%", y: "1%" },
  { text: "Deuxième", x: "60%", y: "2%" },
  { text: "Troisième", x: "20%", y: "3%" },
  { text: "Quatrième", x: "70%", y: "4%" },
  { text: "Cinquième", x: "30%", y: "5%" }
];

let svg = document.getElementById("svg");
drawText(svg, words, (fontSize = 16));
function drawText(svg, words) {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  //const svg = document.createElementNS(ns, "svg");
  words.forEach((word) => {
    let textEl = document.createElementNS(ns, "text");
    let { text, x, y } = word;

    textEl.setAttribute("font-size", fontSize);
    textEl.setAttribute("x", x);
    textEl.setAttribute("y", y);

    // baseline adjust
    textEl.setAttribute("dy", fontSize);
    textEl.textContent = text;
    svg.append(textEl);
  });
}

drawLines(svg);
function drawLines(svg, margin = 5) {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  let textEls = svg.querySelectorAll("text");
  for (let i = 1; i < textEls.length; i += 1) {
    let textEl0 = textEls[i - 1];
    let textEl = textEls[i];
    let bb0 = textEl0.getBBox();
    let bb = textEl.getBBox();

    let x1, x2, y1, y2;
    //left to right
    if (bb0.x < bb.x) {
      x1 = bb0.x + bb0.width + margin;
      y1 = bb0.y + bb0.height / 2;
      x2 = bb.x - margin;
      y2 = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
    }
    // right to left
    else {
      x1 = bb.x + bb.width + margin;
      y1 = bb.y + bb.height / 2;
      x2 = bb0.x - margin;
      y2 = bb0.y + bb0.height / 2;
    }
    let line = document.createElementNS(ns, "line");
    line.setAttribute("stroke-width", "1");
    line.setAttribute("stroke", "#000");
    line.setAttribute("x1", x1);
    line.setAttribute("y1", y1);
    line.setAttribute("x2", x2);
    line.setAttribute("y2", y2);
    svg.append(line);
  }
}
```

```css
svg{
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 1500 900">
  </svg>
```

The main advantage: your diagram could be scaled proportionally.

Drawbacks:
`<text>` elements don't behave like HTML block elements: if you need e.g borders - you'd need to calculate `<rect>` elements according to the `<text>` element's bounding box.
You might also use [`<foreignObject>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) for more complex text box contents. However, foreignObjects can only be displayed in web browsers – most graphic or viewing applications can't render them.